# Getting "return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)" error while working with pandas library

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I wanted to try this snippit of code I found on the Internet,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib

dftrain = pd.read_csv("train.csv", header=0, delimiter=",")  # training data
dfeval = pd.read_csv("eval.csv", header=0, delimiter=",")  # testing data
# print(dftrain)
y_train = dftrain.pop('survived')
y_eval = dfeval.pop('survived')


CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['sec', 'n_siblings_spouses', 'parch', 'class', 'deck', 'embark_town', 'alone']
NUMERICAL_COLUMNS = ['age', 'fare']

feature_columns = []
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
    vocabulary = dftrain[feature_name].unique()
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))

for feature_name in NUMERICAL_COLUMNS:
    feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))
```

unfortunately I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Michael\PycharmProjects\learningTensorv3\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'sec'
```

(It has to be connected to the first "for" statement, but I coudn't figure it out on my own so I am hoping someone could help me)
There are 2 other instances of this error on Stack overflow and in both of them it was just pandas behaving strangely.
I tried reinstalling all libraries, checking for IDE updates (I use PyCharm), using older versions of libraries and changing that "for" statement, unfortunately nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This may not be the root cause of your error, but I came across this
> post when getting the same error.

- For me the root cause was purely a tired error on my part where I had
  referred to a `requests.get` call that was not assigned correctly.
- The program did not error out until several lines later when I tried
  to do a `transformation` on my df column that initially referenced the
  api data that did not exist.